# How to use python on eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I want to use python on Eclipse. How do I do that?

I'm using Eclipse 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. If it is not related to Ubuntu where should I ask this?

Comment: If you are indeed using Ubuntu please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/662054/edit) your question and add the version you are using. It will help others as well. see http://linoob.com/2011/09/starting-with-python-on-eclipse-in-ubuntu/

Comment: This is 100% on ubuntu, this should not be closed. Good question Vesal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Help menu > Install new software. Add this update site:

```
http://pydev.org/updates
```

Select "PyDev for Eclipse" and follow the installation instructions.

[Here is more detailed](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)